# Open Bank Account with one year work permit in Malaysia

Tags: working-visas, banking

I'm an expat on a work permit in Malaysia. This is the second company I joined, few months back. Previously I worked for another company which provided me a three-year work permit. With the new company, although my position is permanent, the company refused to apply for a work permit longer than a year, saying it's the company policy.

One of the banks that I need to open account with, is CitiBank. However, the bank *strictly* requires at least 1 year visa. By the time I receive my passport, it is less than a year. Last time I visited the bank I had 7 months left in my Visa in addition to employment contract stating I'm a permanent employee. Unfortunately, it did not help.

My question, is there any other way to open a bank account with CitiBank Malaysia with less than a year visa?

Comment: Why does it have to be CitiBank specifically? Can't you use one of the other banks?

Comment: Working here in Thailand, sometimes an employer will say you must open an account with the same bank that they bank with, simply so they can avoid the bank charges when paying someone whose account is with another bank. It also avoids delays in payment of salary.

Answer (score 1):

The best option might be to ask your employer to give you a longer contract, and explain to them that you can't open a bank account for them to pay your salary with a 1 year contract. They might understand and extend.